# How to handle roles in a custom role class in asp.net Core 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-2.0

I have a custom `IdentityRole` called `ApplicationRole`. I created a RoleManager Service and I was successful in creating new roles using `CreateAsync` method but I am facing two issues here.

1. I can't get all roles using this implementation (`GetAllRolesAsync`). I keep getting this error,

> Cannot implicitly convert type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'

2. I keep receiving
   `concurrency failure` upon using `DeleteAsync`

> Optimistic concurrency failure, object has been modified.

I am posting the relevant code for this implementation.

**`ApplicationRole Class`**

```
  public class ApplicationRole: IdentityRole
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

**`ApplicationRoleViewModel class`**

```
public class ApplicationRoleViewModel
{
    public string RoleId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Display(Name = "Role Name")]
    public string RoleName { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

**Registering `Identity` Service**

```
 services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>
```

**`Registering RoleManager Service`**

```
services.AddScoped<IRoleManager, RoleManager>();
```

**`RoleManager` Service**

```
public interface IRoleManager
    {
        Task<List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>> GetAllRolesAsync();
        Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationRoleViewModel model);
        Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(ApplicationRoleViewModel model);
    }
    public class RoleManager : IRoleManager
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager;
        public RoleManager(RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
        {

            this.roleManager = roleManager;

        }
        public Task<IdentityResult> CreateAsync(ApplicationRoleViewModel model)
        {
            ApplicationRole role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = model.RoleName;
            return this.roleManager.CreateAsync((role));
        }
        public Task<IdentityResult> DeleteAsync(ApplicationRoleViewModel model)
        {
            ApplicationRole role = new ApplicationRole();
            role.Name = model.RoleName;
            return this.roleManager.DeleteAsync((role));
        }

        public Task<List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>> GetAllRolesAsync()
        {
            var roles = this.roleManager.Roles.ToList();
            return roles;
        }

    }
```

**`UserManagementController`**

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAllRoles() {
    var roles = this.roleManager.GetAllRolesAsync();
    return Ok(roles);
} 

[HttpDelete]
 public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteIdentityRole([FromBody] ApplicationRoleViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        IdentityResult result = await this.roleManager.DeleteAsync(model);
        if (result.Succeeded)
            return Ok(model.RoleName + " role has been created successfully");

    return BadRequest(result.Errors);

}
```

Comment: Adding this as a comment since it really only answers your first issue. `GetAllRolesAsync` wants a Task to be returned, but you're just returning the list. You could call `ToListAsync()` if it exists, instead, or when returning the list, wrap it in `Task.FromResult()` to return a completed task with the list.

Comment: in the first implementation, I am trying to return a `Task` not `async` tho', I call `async` in my controller actions, yet I can't return the list. the error says, `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task'`

Comment: The `Async` method variants return a task. If the method calling the async method doesn't need to wait on the result, it could just return the task. So, you can either return the task `ToListAsync()` returns, if that is available on your collection, or if it's unavailable, you can `return Task.FromResult(roles);`, which will return your list wrapped in task, to match the declaration.

Comment: Surely you need to `await` on `GetAllRolesAsync`. With regard to the delete problem I'm guessing you need to retrieve the entity in order to delete it.

Comment: @MattSieker, I am updating my comment, `ToListAsync()` does not exist in the collection but Task.FromResult(roles); worked only for retrieving roles names!, not the whole model,,,,, worked in this implementation only,,,       `public Task<List<string>> GetAllRolesNameAsync()
        {
            var roles = roleManager.Roles.
            Select(r=>r.Name).ToList();
             return Task.FromResult(roles);
        }` . I want to return the whole model.